# store the data coming from database in generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am using generic list to store the data that comes by querying the databse.I uses List of classes actually for multiple rows.
But my problem is my classes have almost more than 20 properties and most of the time i uses only its 2 or 3 properties.
So I want to know that what is the best  way to keep the data coming from database.

Below is my code

```
List<ImageGalleryCollection> tempList = new List<ImageGalleryCollection1>();
SqlConnection connection = Dal.GetConnection();
SqlParameter[] paramList = new SqlParameter[1];
paramList[0] = new SqlParameter("@cityId", cityId);
SqlDataReader data = Dal.ExecuteReaderSP(SPNames.GetRegCity, paramList, connection);

while(data.Read())
{
    ImageGalleryCollection igc = new ImageGalleryCollection1();

    igc.cityPhotoGalleryId = Convert.ToInt32(data["cityPhotoGalleryId"]);     
    igc.ImagePath = data["imagePath"].ToString();
    tempList.Add(igc);        
}

data.Close();
connection.Close();
return tempList;
```

In ImageGalleryCollection  I have more that 20 properties and above i only uses two properties.I think it is very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Can you how your base class implementation? You can create another class with the most using attributes and use an object of that class inside your class.

Comment: In that case i have to create multiple classes

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<ImageGalleryCollection> GetImageGalleryCollection()
{    

        SqlConnection connection = Dal.GetConnection();
        SqlParameter[] paramList = new SqlParameter[1];
        paramList[0] = new SqlParameter("@cityId", cityId);
        SqlDataReader data = Dal.ExecuteReaderSP(SPNames.GetRegCity, paramList,connection);
        while(data.Read())
        {
           ImageGalleryCollection igc = new ImageGalleryCollection1();

           igc.cityPhotoGalleryId = Convert.ToInt32(data["cityPhotoGalleryId"]);     
            igc.ImagePath = data["imagePath"].ToString();
            yield return igc;

        }
        data.Close();
        connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to write a extension method for `SqlDataReader` and make use of the method in `linq` to fetch required columns from the returned rows of reader.

Extension method:

```
public static class DataReaderExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Object[]> DataRecord(this System.Data.IDataReader source)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

            while (source.Read())
            {
                Object[] row = new Object[source.FieldCount];
                source.GetValues(row);
                yield return row;
            }
        }
    }
```

using it in linq:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblUser"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var result = (from row in dr.DataRecord()
                                      select new
                                         {
                                             UserId = row[0],
                                             UserName = row[1]
                                         }).ToList();                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

This result list has only the required properties you select and helps to reduce the consumption of memory for unwanted properties.

Comment: but we are not able to pass var result to another page when we use linq